# how to make popup box based on dropdown list selection using jquery

Tags: jquery-ui

I have three columns in the jquery grid with all three column has dropdown list boxes.

if you select first dropdown list box any value i need to enable second one. if you select second I need to enable third one using jquery.

Comment: you just want the second select box to be enabled when something is selected from the first? same goes for the third select?

Answer (score 0):

one of the coolest things about jquery is its ability to handle events in the DOM.

the event you're looking for is .change() http://api.jquery.com/change/

the html markup for 2 select elements

```
<select id="first_select">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="second_select" disabled="disabled">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

javascript/jquery to handle changes to the select boxes

```
$("#first_select").change(function() {
  $("#second_select").removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

The second select element will be enabled when a change is made to the first. Follow this logic for the third select.

Comment: Thanks.. But if my dropdown list box values will be jquery column type.. 
that is something like
{ name: 'N', index: '', edittype: 'select',editype:true, width: 100, editoptions: { value: { 1: 'AA', 2: 'CC',3:'BD''}} }
hw to handle this type of things
Thanks

Comment: can you give a link to the jquery column/grid stuff you're using